# Change Magento body background for each cat ID

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How to change Magento body background for each cat ID ? And Where to put the code??

I know that Cat id is :

`Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it off category name quite easily.  Magento, by default, adds the following to the body tag:

```
<body class="catalog-category-view categorypath-electronics-cellphones category-cellphones">
```

It follows that you could define your stylesheet to work off the `.category-{$category_name}` class instead of a `.category-{$category_id}`, or similar.  It would make more sense to the next person that comes along and edits your stylesheet too :)

Back to your question, if you would actually like to modify the code and actually used a category ID, then you'd have to modify the category controller, in the usual manner, and add:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getId());
```

..in the `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction()` at around the same point as the other classes are added.

Comment: +1 for using the name instead of ID. That is much nicer to use and potentially more resilient to change - if a category was replaced with an identical one it's ID would be different and break the style.

Comment: This is a nice answer though it may lack flexibility for some store owner. This is from a real client case where the client wanted the category image (from backend) to be the background for the relevant category (on the frontend). The solution is great for who may have CSS skills which not the case of many clients :) So here is what I did : add a hidden div in category/view.phtml with the category img url // use JS to get the content of this hidden div and to change the CSS background of let's say .main or .col-main for instance using the content of the hidden div. That works beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that is flexible enough for a webstore owner to use in conjunction with their web designer (to apply the css rule).

Scenario: you want the same background image for a category & its children.

1) You apply a layout update to the parent category within the Category manager:

`<reference name=”root”><action method=”addBodyClass”><className>caravan-motorhome-lighting</className></action></reference>`

2) Set the parent category **not to** Use Parent Category Settings.

3) Set the child categories to Use Parent Category Settings

4) add body class declaration like so body.caravan-motorhome-lighting{background: url(..)}

You can find a fuller explanation [Magento - changing the body class by category](http://www.eddiemay.me.uk/2011/11/07/magento-changing-the-body-class-by-category/)

I've used this technique in Magento 1.6.1.0 but should work with earlier versions where you can apply layout updates to a category.